using NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE
I'm building on Visual Studio 2019 and using nlohmann json.hpp
And getting this compiler error:
C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const TestClass1' (or there is no acceptable conversion).
class TestClass1 
{ 
public: 
    virtual TestClass1 & operator = (const TestClass1 & o) 
    { 
        return *this; 
    } 

    int t1; 
}; 

class TestClass 
{ 
public: 
    TestClass1 tt1; 
}; 

NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE(TestClass,tt1)

Unrelated: Don't forget the self check in assignment.

Found the issue!
The macro NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE has to be used on every type that is a member of the target class.
In my case, the macro should also be used for TestClass1 as follows:
NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_NON_INTRUSIVE(TestClass1,t1)
